# Can a local function replace\override itself in Lua

Tags: function, lua

In Lua is it possible to replace a local function from within itself? For example:

```
local function emptyFunction(arg)
    return
end

local function exampleFunction(arg)
    local result, err = io.open("/tmp/BadFile","w")
    if result == nil then
        print(err)
        exampleFunction = emptyFunction
        return
    end
    io.close(result)
end
```

Comment: Yes, but it won't override any other references to it. `local keptFunction = exampleFunction; keptFunction(); keptFunction();`

Comment: You can easily test this by yourself in the interpreter...

Comment: @MatteoItalia - It is and I had pretty much written all the code in the question already in the question but testing the code I wrote doesn't exactly answer the question in enough detail.

As ColonelThirtyTwo has pointed out I can use it to replace\override the function but it won't work as expected if the function has already been stored in another reference.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: If you want to adapt your comment to an answer I can mark it as the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redefine a function within the function itself, you need a reference to the function in a variable that has already been declared *before* the variable is assigned a reference to the function.

First example -- how not to do it -- does not work because "fx" *is not in scope* inside fx, as intuition suggests (to me) it would not be.

Frankly, I don't know how to precisely describe what "fx" inside the function represents -- but it seems to be a global variable that is in a scope that is somehow "more global than a 'global local' declaration."

In the global space, I always assumed these two were equivalent:

```
foo = 'bar';
local foo = 'bar';
```

Precisely speaking, they apparently are not genuinely equivalent, *if* you have a way of accessing both.  This first example does exactly that, and here's why:

When you do this...

```
local myfunc = function () ...
```

... what are you actually doing?

You're **first** declaring an anonymous function, and **second** declaring "myfunc" and **third** setting "myfunc" as a reference to the anonymous function you just created.  Until the moment the function begins to exist, "local myfunc" does not yet exist, because the statement that declares it hasn't actually been executed yet.  (At least, that's how I perceive it.)

Here's the non-working version that illustrates this:

```
local fx = function ()
    print(fx);
    print("inside the original fx")
    fx = function() print "I was redefined" end
end

function f2()
     print("f2")
     f2 = fx
end

f = f2

print(fx);

fx(); fx(); f2(); f2() f();


function: 0x21a6140     -- original "fx" ref is in "global local fx"
nil                     -- inner "fx" -- NOT set on first iteration, so it
inside the original fx  -- can't be the same varliable
function: 0x21a6510     -- now it's set, but to new function,
inside the original fx  -- but the "global local fx" does not contain our new function
f2
function: 0x21a6510
inside the original fx
f2
```

Second example, we declare local fx first, and then set it to a reference to the function.  There are no other changes.

```
local fx;       -- declare before assignment
fx = function ()
    print(fx);
    print("inside the original fx")
    fx = function() print "I was redefined" end
end

function f2()
     print("f2")
     f2 = fx
end

f = f2

print(fx);

fx(); fx(); f2(); f2() f();


function: 0x2188e50      -- original function
function: 0x2188e50      -- same reference, so this one *is* in scope
inside the original fx 
I was redefined          -- and redefining it works exactly as expected
f2
I was redefined
f2
```

So, yes, there is a way.  You need a global local variable that is declared, and subsequently you need to set that to a reference to the function so that it is in scope in the function that tries to redefine it.

In a similar way, the `f2` function can't redefine itself.  It only redefines what `f2` means, inside `f2` while `f2()` is running.

Comment: "redefine a function" doesn't make sense. A function is an immutable value. You are talking about reassigning a variable.

Comment: @TomBlodget you are, of course, correct, and my terminology is imprecise. What we are doing is changing what happens when you call the function referenced by the variable, but in casual parlance, we "call function fx" even though we're actually calling the function referenced by fx.  It is in that casual sense that I am saying the "function" is being redefined, or perhaps (?) more correctly "replaced."  This is what the second example does, and the first example fails to do.  I'll try to clarify.

Comment: I'm actually still fairly new at Lua, so for all I know, it may not even be correct to say the variable holds a "reference" to the function.  I'm thinking in terms of Perl coderefs, `my $f; $f = sub { ... }; $f->();`.

Comment: The Reference Manual uses that term: "Tables, functions, threads, and (full) userdata values are objects: variables do not actually contain these values, only references to them". I haven't used Perl since JavaScript took over the world but coderefs seem quite similar.

Comment: My actual use case isn't actually as complicated as this since I have everything locally defined so both @SergiiMartynenkoJr and Michael - sqlbot are correct for what I need but I think Michael - sqlbot provides more info for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents you from doing so. Local or not function name in Lua is actually variable name which points to function itself. 
So there is no any difference between

```
local function f1()
   ...
end
```

and

```
local f1 = function()  
                ... 
           end
```

In both cases `f1` is in scope of function body.

However, such replace won't change no any external references

```
function f1()
    print("f1")
end

function f2()
     print("f2")
     f2 = f1
end

f = f2

f1(); f2(); f2() f();
```

will lead to output

```
 f1
 f2
 f1
 f2
```

Note, that if you add `local` keyword to declarations - nothing changes

Comment: Even easier way to showcase that than calling the functions would be to `print` them directly and compare the hashes.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, but before you should call `f2()` or `f()` at least once

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr - In your second example `local f1 = function()...end` f1 is NOT in scope of function body

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff why not? Actually, I've tested it, and it is in the scope

Comment: If it is, that seems very counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Well, why is it? After all, local variable in global scope is, actually, global variable =).

Comment: That was always my assumption, but this question prompted me to realize that it isn't *quite* true. See what you think of my answer.

Comment: "function name in Lua is actually variable name which points to function itself" Sort of: A function is a value. Values don't have names; Variables do. (And, values have types; Variables don't.)